# Python decoding weird characters

Tags: python, decode, encode

C�r�monie, how would I decode these characters in python to cérémonie?

```
 line.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

I've tried to decode it in "latin-1" and "utf-8" but get the same results: Cï¿½rï¿½monie. Since "line" is a string I can't decode it directly?

I tried to use and encoding when i opened the file too, but get the same result: Cï¿½rï¿½monie

```
f = open('data/u.item', 'r', encoding='latin-1')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python3

Comment: Did you write the code that originally wrote the data in that file, or is it being produced by some process that you don't have any control over?

Comment: If you open the file in binary mode: `f=open('data/u.item', 'rb')` what does `print(repr(line))` print?

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't processed by me, and I just realized that some data in the file was corrupted. Feel so stupid now ^^. Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries. Decoding files with unknown encodings can be tricky at the best of times, but it's rather hard when the file is corrupt. :)

Comment: you can try `chardet` library to detect encoding, and then decode corrupted string

Answer (score 1):

I use binaire (2.7):

i do that because python was not capable to read my string

example of use :

i separate string (data) in "binaire string"

```
binaire = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in data)
```

i find wich char corespond with wich

```
print binaire
```

i replace with byte: example

```
binaire = binaire.replace("11101010", "1100101")  # replace ê by e in my case
```

i reconverte my string in python string

```
res = bitstring_to_bytes(binaire)



def bitstring_to_bytes(tab):
      tab = tab.split(" ")
      string = ""
      for t in tab:
            string  = string + bitchar_to_bytes(t)
      return string

def bitchar_to_bytes(s):
    v = int(s, 2)
    b = bytearray()
    while v:
          b.append(v & 0xff)
      v >>= 8
    return bytes(b[::-1])
```